# Can someone explain this angled bracket tensor notation?

Tags: physics, tensors

[image]

This is the equation for the luminosity of gravitational waves from a pair of rotating bodies, with quadrupole tensor Q.

[image]

Can anyone explain the meaning of the angled bracket notation here?
I know that it usually denotes the inner product, but that usually looks like $<a,b>$.

I found a paper which describes the same thing in this way: [image]

But that doesn't really help me.

I know almost nothing about tensor mathematics... I just need to compute the summation given in the first equation, given the tensor Q. If someone could explain how, that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's Dirac or Bra-ket notation.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation